# How to Convert CSV to deeply nested JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, csv

Python code I am using:

```py
import csv
import json

class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, set):
            return list(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def str_to_bool(s):
    if s == "TRUE":
        return True
    elif s == "FALSE":
        return False
    else:
        return None
file = "sample"
csvfile = open(f'csv/{file}.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
next(csvfile, None) 
jsonfile = open(f'output/{file}.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("key", "name", "loc_type",
"loc_id", "cities_name", "shippingMethods_name",
"isExcluded", "cutoffWindows_startTime", "cutoffWindows_endTime",
"cutoffWindows_capacity", "cutoffWindows_slots", "category",
"furniture", "removeFallbacks", "cutoffWindows")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    row['furniture'] = str_to_bool(row.pop('furniture'))
    cities_name = row.pop('cities_name')
    row['cities'] = [{'name': cities_name}]
    for smethod in row['cities']:
        shippingMethods_name = row.pop('shippingMethods_name')
        isExcluded = row.pop('isExcluded')
        removeFallbacks = row.pop('removeFallbacks')
        smethod['shippingMethods'] = [{'name': shippingMethods_name, 'isExcluded': str_to_bool(isExcluded), 'removeFallbacks': str_to_bool(removeFallbacks)}]
        for cwindows in smethod['shippingMethods']:
            cutoffWindows = row.pop('cutoffWindows')
            startTime = row.pop('cutoffWindows_startTime')
            endTime = row.pop('cutoffWindows_endTime')
            capacity = row.pop('cutoffWindows_capacity')
            cwindows['cutoffWindows'] = [{'startTime': startTime, 'endTime': endTime, 'capacity': capacity}]
            for s in cwindows['cutoffWindows']:
                slots = row.pop('cutoffWindows_slots')
                s['slots'] = [{slots}]

    json.dump(row, jsonfile, indent=4, cls=SetEncoder)
    jsonfile.write(',')
```

Sample file:

```
key,name,loc_type,loc_id,cities_name,shippingMethods_name,isExcluded,cutoffWindows_startTime,cutoffWindows_endTime,cutoffWindows_capacity,cutoffWindows_slots,category,furniture,removeFallbacks,Mode,Country,sm_omscode,slots_omscode
store-fashion,UAE - Store (Fashion),S,8502,dubai,next-day-delivery,FALSE,0:01,23:59,20,9pm12am,fashion,,,Normal,BloomingDales AE,NEXTDAY,SLOT21-24
store-fashion,UAE - Store (Fashion),S,8502,dubai,1-3-days-delivery,FALSE,0:01,23:59,,,fashion,,TRUE,Normal,BloomingDales AE,1TO3DAYS,
store-fashion,UAE - Store (Fashion),S,8502,non-dubai,next-day-delivery,FALSE,0:01,21:00,40,12am12am,fashion,,,Normal,BloomingDales AE,NEXTDAY,NEXTDAY
store-fashion,UAE - Store (Fashion),S,8502,non-dubai,1-3-days-delivery,TRUE,0:01,23:59,,,fashion,TRUE,TRUE,Normal,BloomingDales AE,1TO3DAYS,
```

Current output:

```json
{
    "key": "store-fashion",
    "name": "UAE - Store (Fashion)",
    "loc_type": "S",
    "loc_id": "8502",
    "category": "fashion",
    "null": [
        "BloomingDales AE",
        "NEXTDAY",
        "SLOT21-24"
    ],
    "furniture": null,
    "cities": [
        {
            "name": "dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [
                {
                    "name": "next-day-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "removeFallbacks": null,
                    "cutoffWindows": [
                        {
                            "startTime": "0:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": "20",
                            "slots": [
                                [
                                    "9pm12am"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},{
    "key": "store-fashion",
    "name": "UAE - Store (Fashion)",
    "loc_type": "S",
    "loc_id": "8502",
    "category": "fashion",
    "null": [
        "BloomingDales AE",
        "1TO3DAYS",
        ""
    ],
    "furniture": null,
    "cities": [
        {
            "name": "dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [
                {
                    "name": "1-3-days-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "removeFallbacks": true,
                    "cutoffWindows": [
                        {
                            "startTime": "0:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": "",
                            "slots": [
                                [
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},{
    "key": "store-fashion",
    "name": "UAE - Store (Fashion)",
    "loc_type": "S",
    "loc_id": "8502",
    "category": "fashion",
    "null": [
        "BloomingDales AE",
        "NEXTDAY",
        "NEXTDAY"
    ],
    "furniture": null,
    "cities": [
        {
            "name": "non-dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [
                {
                    "name": "next-day-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "removeFallbacks": null,
                    "cutoffWindows": [
                        {
                            "startTime": "0:01",
                            "endTime": "21:00",
                            "capacity": "40",
                            "slots": [
                                [
                                    "12am12am"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},{
    "key": "store-fashion",
    "name": "UAE - Store (Fashion)",
    "loc_type": "S",
    "loc_id": "8502",
    "category": "fashion",
    "null": [
        "BloomingDales AE",
        "1TO3DAYS",
        ""
    ],
    "furniture": true,
    "cities": [
        {
            "name": "non-dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [
                {
                    "name": "1-3-days-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": true,
                    "removeFallbacks": true,
                    "cutoffWindows": [
                        {
                            "startTime": "0:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": "",
                            "slots": [
                                [
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected result:

```json
[{
    "key": "store-fashion",
    "name": "UAE - Store (Fashion)",
    "loc_type": "S",
    "loc_id": "8502",
    "cities": [{
            "name": "dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [{
                    "name": "same-day-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "cutoffWindows": [{
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "10:00",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "1pm6pm"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "16:00",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "6pm9pm"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "16:00",
                            "capacity": 15,
                            "slots": [
                                "9pm12am"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "next-day-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "cutoffWindows": [{
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "21:00",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "9am1pm"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "1pm5pm"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "6pm9pm"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "startTime": "00:01",
                            "endTime": "23:59",
                            "capacity": 20,
                            "slots": [
                                "9pm12am"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "1-3-days-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "removeFallbacks": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "non-dubai",
            "shippingMethods": [{
                    "name": "next-day-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "cutoffWindows": [{
                        "startTime": "00:01",
                        "endTime": "21:00",
                        "capacity": 40,
                        "slots": [
                            "12am12am"
                        ]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "name": "1-3-days-delivery",
                    "isExcluded": false,
                    "removeFallbacks": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Issues:

1. I am expecting one object to be created with nested data on it but the data is repeating based on the number of lines of the csv data even though the key is the same
2. I have defined fields in the fieldnames but data that is not part of it is still coming in the json file
3. empty fields in the csv data are still coming in json
4. data is supposed to be in inside an array [], and it should end NOT in "," if there is multiple keys

Thank you so much, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too big a problem to expect anyone to completely solve, but I'd like to help you get started.  I see this problem as recognizing that from the flat 2D data, we need to create hierarchies as we read left-to-right: a list of keys, each key with a list of cities, each city with a list of shipping methods, etc...

I cannot fit that all in my head at once so I'm going to break up the problem into many steps, and actually start from the end and work backwards from the final Python dict to the CSV file.

The final Python dict, before passing it to json.dump(), needs to look like something like the following stripped-down example:

```py
final = [
    {
        "key": "store-fashion",
        "loc_id": "8502",
        "loc_type": "S",
        "cities": [
            {
                "name": "dubai",
                "shippingMethods": [
                    {"name": "1-3-days-delivery", "isExcluded": False},
                    {"name": "next-day-delivery", "isExcluded": False},
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "non-dubai",
                "shippingMethods": [
                    {"name": "1-3-days-delivery", "isExcluded": False},
                    {"name": "next-day-delivery", "isExcluded": False},
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

(Your data has more hierarchys under shipping methods—cut-off windows, then slots—but I'm going to stop at shipping methods.)

How do we get to that final structure?  I see creating the following three data structures, then stitching them together:

- a dict of keys, with named references to cities
- a dict of cities, with named references to shipping methods
- a dict of shipping methods, with...

```py
keys = {
    "store-fashion": {
        "loc_id": "8502",
        "loc_type": "S",
        "_cities": set(["dubai", "non-dubai"]),
    }
}

cities = {
    "dubai": {
        "_shippingMethods": set(["next-day-delivery", "1-3-days-delivery"]),
    },
    "non-dubai": {
        "_shippingMethods": set(["next-day-delivery", "1-3-days-delivery"]),
    },
}

ship_methods = {
    "next-day-delivery": {"isExcluded": False},
    "1-3-days-delivery": {"isExcluded": False},
}
```

keys has the _cities references which point to individual cities, cities has the _shippingMethods references which point to individual ship methods.

To stitch them together I start at the top with keys, creating a new_key object and immediately iterating its cities and doing the same for each city.  This process continues for every nested hierarchy.  Each new_object is appended to the list of objects only after everything below it has been appened (creating the hierarchy from the bottom-up):

```py
final_test = []
for key_name in keys:
    key_props = keys[key_name]
    new_key = {"key": key_name}
    new_key.update(key_props)
    del new_key["_cities"]
    new_key["cities"] = []

    for city_name in sorted(key_props["_cities"]):
        city_props = cities[city_name]
        new_city = {"name": city_name}
        new_city["shippingMethods"] = []

        for shipmeth_name in sorted(city_props["_shipMethods"]):
            shipmeth_props = ship_methods[shipmeth_name]
            new_shipmeth = {"name": shipmeth_name}
            new_shipmeth.update(shipmeth_props)

            new_city["shippingMethods"].append(new_shipmeth)

        new_key["cities"].append(new_city)

    final_test.append(new_key)

assert final_test == final
```

And that works!

On to the CSV file and getting those rows of data into keys, cities, and ship_methods.  Again, I think this problem is too big to try and do everything in one pass.  I'll read the whole CSV file in to a variable once, then loop over the rows of that variable for as many groupings as I need to create.

I'll use the csv.DictReader(), like you were, but I'll use the header names as they are:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    csv_data = list(reader)

print(csv_data)
```

```py
[
    {'key': 'store-fashion', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Fashion)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'dubai',     ...
    {'key': 'store-fashion', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Fashion)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'dubai',     ...
    {'key': 'store-fashion', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Fashion)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'non-dubai', ...
    {'key': 'store-fashion', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Fashion)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'non-dubai', ...
]
```

For each grouping/hierarchy I need I iterate the rows focusing only the columns that make up that grouping.

For keys I copy only the columns I want with `{key: row[key] for key in ["loc_id", "loc_type"]}`:

```py
keys_test = {}
for row in csv_data:
    Key = row["key"]

    if Key not in keys_test:
        keys_test[Key] = {key: row[key] for key in ["loc_id", "loc_type"]}
        keys_test[Key]["_cities"] = set()

    keys_test[Key]["_cities"].add(row["cities_name"])

assert keys_test == keys
```

Cities don't have any data to copy besides the name:

```py
cities_test = {}
for row in csv_data:
    City = row["cities_name"]

    if City not in cities_test:
        cities_test[City] = {"_shippingMethods": set()}

    cities_test[City]["_shippingMethods"].add(row["shippingMethods_name"])

assert cities_test == cities
```

For the boolean conversion, I do it directly in the assingment:

```py
ship_methods_test = {}
for row in csv_data:
    Shipmeth = row["shippingMethods_name"]

    if Shipmeth not in ship_methods_test:
        ship_methods_test[Shipmeth] = {}
        ship_methods_test[Shipmeth]["isExcluded"] = row["isExcluded"] == "TRUE"
        # add set for cut-off windows

    # add cut-off window to set

assert ship_methods_test == ship_methods
```

Here's a sketch of how it will all look when put together:

```py
# read CSV

# iterate CSV and group keys
# iterate CSV and group cities
# iterate CSV and group ship methods
# iterate CSV and group cut-off windows
# iterate CSV and group slots

# stitch together
# for key in keys
    # for city in cities
        # for ship_method in ship_methods
            # for cutoff_window in cutoff_windows
                # for slot in slots

                    # append slot
                # append cutoff_window
            # append ship_method
        # append city
    # append key
```

Comment: Hi @Zach Young, 3 things that is written in your About are all true :) Thank you so much for this beautiful well written code. I will start to execute now the and revert back

Comment: I am encountering Assertion Error

assert keys_test == keys
AssertionError

This happens if there are multiple unique keys in the csv

[
    {'key': 'store-fashion', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Fashion)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'dubai',     ...
    {'key': 'store-home', 'name': 'UAE - Store (Home)', 'loc_type': 'S', 'loc_id': '8502', 'cities_name': 'dubai',     ...
]

First time using assertion, no idea about this :)

Comment: I encourage you to look up assert for Python, it’s just a way of coding that you expect something to be true and failing otherwise. In your case, your real data has keys that the sample does not. Those assert … test statements helped me when I was developing and debugging this solution. They’ll have limited value for you as is. Still, I encourage you to make sure you understand why those statements are not true, before you ultimately remove them. And, since I cannot solve your problem for you, if this solution gets you _started_, please consider accepting it… checkmark at upper left.